# GCC -H option issue (header dependency tree listing)

Tags: c++, gcc, c-preprocessor, header-files

GCC can display all header dependencies of a .cpp file in a tree structure if the -H option is passed.
It's a very handy feature because

1) it produces the output after/while evaluating the defines passed in the -D parameter,

2) it uses the same include paths which would be used during compilation.

There is one problem with its behavior which is very frustrating.
**If the content of an included header file evaluates to empty string during repeated inclusion** (because of the content being enclosed in an #ifndef statement), **then the included header file name is not listed as a dependency of any subsequent header files**.

I will add a very brief example here:

```
// main.cpp
#include "header1.h"
int main(void) {
  return 0;
}

// header1.h
#ifndef header1_h
#define header1_h
#include "header2.h"
#include "header3.h"
#endif

// header2.h
#ifndef header2_h
#define header2_h
#include "header3.h"
#endif

// header3.h
#ifndef header3_h
#define header3_h
void header3_function1(void);
#endif
```

I would expect this as correct output of "gcc.exe -H -c main.cpp":

```
. header1.h
.. header2.h
... header3.h
.. header3.h
```

Actual output:

```
. header1.h
.. header2.h
... header3.h
```

So I think that header3.h should be listed as a dependency of header1.h as well, even though its contents evaluate to empty string at that specific point.

**Is there any way to force GCC to display the missing nodes in the tree?**

**Or alternatively, is there any other compiler or preprocessor which can execute this task properly?**

Note 1:
Displaying the missing nodes would not introduce any amounts of redundancy in the tree because even if header3.h had a large dependency subtree, it would not be listed in the output more than once because of the #ifndef statement.

Note 2:
I have one work-around which is not an acceptable solution. If I append a dummy #define line at the end (outside the #ifndef block) of each header file in the application, then the missing nodes will appear. (But obviously modifying a large number of files in a repository - including built-in system headers - is not acceptable as a solution.)

Thanks

Comment: Hmm I think I agree with you - it seems like (a) GCC is "optimising" the header guard into more of a `#pragma once`, and (b) considering such logic when generating the dependency tree. I think your best bet is a bug report or feature request on their Bugzilla. Or, at the very least, raise it on a GCC mailing list.

Comment: Have you tried playing with `-dI`? https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options I don't think it's really made for this, but with a bit of grepping it could help

Comment: Is this behaviour the same if there are non-conditional parts in header3.h? I could see this switch losing a bit of its value if the behaviour is changed to your proposal - you couldn't tell any longer if the include guard was `#undef`d in header2.h (which may be bad programming or not, depending on the circumstances i.e. code generation)

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica
I could not get the -dI option to produce any output. I don't know what I am doing wrong.
Anyway, what I have found recently is that MSVC Compiler has a parameter named "showIncludes" which behaves the same way as GCC (it omits empty preprocessed header files from the hierarchy listing).
I am currently trying to extract the information I need from the #line lines of the preprocessor output, we'll see whether this approach can work or not

Comment: The `-dI` option is only valid when preprocessing, not normal compilation, so it has to be used together with `-E`